# Why the jquery function is not triggered?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to trigger a popup box using the function provide by jquery easyui, 
the code are following, it is not trigger : when i click open , there is no popup box opened, 
also the popup box element is not hidden, it should work as i following their tutorial material. Thank you

The code :

Head Extract:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#win').window('open');  
});
</script>
```

Body: extract :

```
<button onclick="javascript:$('#win').window('open')"> Permission Settings</button>

<div id="win" class="easyui-window" closed="true" title="Login" style="width:300px;height:180px;">
        <form style="padding:10px 20px 10px 40px;">
            <p>Name: <input type="text"></p>
            <p>Pass: <input type="password"></p>
            <div style="padding:5px;text-align:center;">
                <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" icon="icon-ok">Ok</a>
                <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" icon="icon-cancel">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Whole part:

```
<?
include("../connection/conn.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

if (!isset($_POST['subscribe']))
$_POST['subscribe']=0;
if (!isset($_POST['unsubscribe']))
$_POST['unsubscribe']=0;

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {

    $listName = $_POST['lname'];
    $listFromName = $_POST['fname'];
    $listReplyTo = $_POST['remail'];
    $listSubject = $_POST['sub'];
    $listRemindSub = $_POST['subscribe'];
    $listRemindUnSub = $_POST['unsubscribe'];
    $listReminder = $_POST['creminder'];

    $query="INSERT INTO list (ListID,ListName,FromName,ReplyTo,Subject,IsRemindSub,IsRemindUnSub,CreateDate,Reminder) VALUES ('',?,?,?,?,?,?,CURDATE(),?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);


    $stmt->bindParam(1, $listName , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $listFromName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $listReplyTo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $listSubject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $listRemindSub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $listRemindUnSub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $listReminder, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();


}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    }


try {
    $lastID=$conn->lastInsertId();
    $query="INSERT INTO require_attributes (ReqID,ListID,Attribute,Tag) VALUES ('',$lastID,'Email','{email}')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $query="INSERT INTO require_attributes (ReqID,ListID,Attribute,Tag) VALUES ('',$lastID,'FirstName','{fname}')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $query="INSERT INTO require_attributes (ReqID,ListID,Attribute,Tag) VALUES ('',$lastID,'LastName','{lname}')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    } 

try {
    $userID = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query="INSERT INTO user_list (UserID,ListID,UserListRights) VALUES (?,$lastID,'Edit')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    }    


$conn = null;

?>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">You have created a list. By default Mail Address, First Name , Last Name is in your list. Add more field if you want. <a href='add.php'>Back</a></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<?
}else{?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/easyui/themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/form.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){
$("#addlist").validate();
});
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
$('#win').window('open');  
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="addlist" method="post" action="add.php" >
<h1>Create your new subscriber list</h1> 
<p>Create a new list before adding subscriber <label class="right"><em class="dot">*</em> indicates required</label></p>

<label><em class="dot">*</em> List name:
<span class="small">Add your list name</span>
</label>
<input id="lname" name="lname" class="required" />

<div class="spacer"></div>

<label>Reminder:
<span class="small">Remind the details of your list</span>
</label>
<textarea id="creminder" name="creminder" cols="52" ></textarea>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<p>Permission Setting ...</p>

<label>Open to other users:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="public" value="1">
Or
<div class="spacer"></div>

<button onclick="javascript:$('#win').window('open')"> Permission Settings</button>

<div id="win" class="easyui-window" closed="true" title="Login" style="width:300px;height:180px;">
            <p>Name: <input type="text"></p>
            <p>Pass: <input type="password"></p>
            <div style="padding:5px;text-align:center;">
                <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-save" onclick="javascript:alert('save')">Save</a>
                <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dd').dialog('close')">Close</a>
            </div>
</div>



<div class="spacer"></div>

<p>Email me when ...</p> 
<label>People subscribe:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="1">
<div class="spacer"></div>
<label>People unsubscribe:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="unsubscribe" value="1">


<div class="spacer"></div>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<?
try{
$sql = '
    SELECT   *
    FROM     list,user_list
    WHERE    user_list.UserID=?
    AND list.ListID=user_list.ListID
';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$result= $stmt->fetchAll();
$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }
$conn = null;
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">You have not created any list yet.</div>';}
else {
    echo '<h1>Your Subscriber List</h1> <p>You have created '.$num_rows.' list(s).</p>';
foreach ($result as $set) 
{
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">List Name : '.$set['FromName'].'</div><br>';
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">Subscriber : </div><br>';
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">Create Date : '.$set['CreateDate'].'</div><br>';
echo '<hr>';
}}
    ?>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?
}
?>
```

Comment: lot of code always confuses so remove extra code that need not to understand your problem

Comment: I think you need to include the plugin script *after* the jQuery script.

Comment: $('#win').window('open'); is the plugin script

Comment: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/win/win1.php

Comment: I am following that tutorial , have a look it is easy and short. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight, the script references are not in the correct order: you need to reference first jQuery and then jQuery EasyUI:

```
<script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Also, what can i do to specific escape the css code ?that is becasue <div class="form css"><div class="popup css">,,,,</div></div> ,  and i want to escape the css code of form

Comment: the other problem is when i click the open button, it act like a submit button and post the form as well as generate a pop up windows.I have not set the button as submit type. Why it behave in a submit type? Thank you.

Comment: Add `return false;` to cancel default behavior of the button. This is though another problem than the question itself.

Comment: so werid . It does not generate the popup after i add return false; but it will still posting my form . why it behave like this?

Comment: I will repost the question because there are more question then i expected. thank you. Please follow the other question if you like

Answer (score 1):

Change your scripts to this order:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/easyui/themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/form.css" />
<script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

so the plugin comes after the jQuery script.

Comment: the other problem is when i click the open button, it act like a submit button and post the form as well as generate a pop up windows.I have not set the button as submit type. Why it behave in a submit type? Thank you.

Comment: <button onclick="javascript:$('#win').window('open')"> Permission Settings</button>